# How to get dynamic month's data depending on the Conditon in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on financial domain.
So I want data from April To May.

**Suppose Current Month IS June** then I only **want April to June of this year** and it should group by year and month.

And **If Suppose Current Month is February** then I want details from **last April to Jan
i.e. April-2013 to Jan-2014**

I have written CTE expression for this I have Got partial result I don't know I am doing wrong or right

```
declare @Month int 
declare @Year int ;
set @Month = 4;
set @Year = YEAR(GETDATE());

if (@Month <= MONTH(GETDATE()))
    with cte as 
    (
    SELECT N = 4, YYY =  YEAR(GETDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1, YYY
    FROM cte
    WHERE N+1 <= MONTH(GETDATE())
    )
    select N, YYY from cte

else  

    with cte as 
    (

    SELECT N = 4 , YYYY = YEAR(GETDATE() - 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1,YYYY
    FROM cte
    WHERE N+1 <= 12     
    )
    select N, YYYY from cte
```

I want O/P something like this

If Current month is greater then April then or more specifically suppose current month is June
then

```
April 2014
May   2014
June  2014
```

If current month is February-2014 then I want

```
April 2013
May   2013
June  2013
July  2013   
Aug   2013 
Sep   2013
Oct   2013
Nov   2013
Dec   2013
Jan   2014
Feb   2014
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS datetime = '20150212';
DECLARE @FirstDayInCurrentMonth AS datetime = DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(day, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate);
DECLARE @LastApril AS datetime = DATEADD(month, -(DATEPART(month, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth) + 8) % 12, @FirstDayInCurrentMonth);

WITH Periods AS (
    SELECT @LastApril AS [Period]
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [Period])
    FROM Periods
    WHERE [Period] < @FirstDayInCurrentMonth
)
SELECT DATENAME(month, [Period])
      ,DATEPART(year, [Period])
FROM Periods
```

Note that this returns only april for days in april. It is not clear from your question if you want 1 or 13 months for days in april.

Comment: hello, Sir. Suppose I current month is June then I want only April,May,June Is it possible

Comment: I want all the days of the months bcoz i want to group by month's will this return all the days

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. What do you want to group? If you have another question, ask a new one. (you can change `DATEADD(month..` to `DATEADD(day..` to get days but it will just repeat the month names)

Comment: No you gave correct answer but I only want to make sure that will it return all the days of the all the months